# Quiero crear un marker draggable usando vb.net. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Tags: vb.net

utilizo
marker = New Markers.GMarkerGoogle(New PointLatLng(-7.2767636, 112.7949036), Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.green)

pero no se como pasar el parametro para que sea draggable

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podes dar un poco mas de contexto? que es esa linea de codigo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.